# how to convert _io.TextIOWrapper to string? im getting always same error

Tags: python

When I run my code I get this error:

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.TextIOWrapper

```
import csv
import os
from time import sleep

class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
        file = ''

    def fileLocation(self,file):
        with open(file) as f:
            if os.path.isfile(f) == True:
                print("Located Succesfully !")
            else:
                while os.path.isfile(f) == False:
                    print("Locate cant find, try again")
                    p = input("Enter correct location : ")
                    if os.path.isdir(p) == True:
                        print("Thanks god, u typed correctly")
                        break

file = input("Enter file location : ")
file = str(file)

def main():
    a = Parser()
    print("Im checking if folder exist...")
    sleep(0.5)
    a.fileLocation(file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to convert to a string, but the result is the same. Any solutions?

Comment: In your `fileLocation`, the `file` variable is the path to the file, not `f`. You can use `file` in the `os.path` methods. You don't need to `open` the file to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `fileLocation`, the `file` variable is the path to the file, not `f`. You can use `file` in the `os.path` methods. You don't need to `open` the file to do that.

*<sub>Copied from [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106390/how-to-convert-io-textiowrapper-to-string-im-getting-always-same-error#comment111592816_63106390)</sub>*

---

To start:

```
def fileLocation(self, file):
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        ...
```

By the way, `== True` is redundant.